# Как телепортироваться по нику spigot

Tags: java, bukkit-api, bukkit

Как телепортировать одного игрока к другому по нику?

Comment: Вам же только вчера закрыли точно такой же вопрос, только там хоть деталей больше было -_-

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в джава, но загуглив *how to tp player bukkit* я нашел довольно много исчерпывающих ответов на разных форумах. Тут конечно не одобряется послать в гугл, но это лучше, чем вообще ничего не ответить. К слову алгоритм может быть следующий: получаете координаты игрока2 и изменяете координаты игрока1 на точно такие же.